# How to create a Flutter widget like this image

Tags: flutter

I want to create a Flutter widget like this image. 'Icon' is a text.
[image]

I read the material design demo of Flutter. But I can't create or find a widget like widget in given image. I am a newbie in Flutter. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a `TextField` like the other answer suggest you can use `InputDecorator`

example:

```
InputDecorator(
  child: Text("TEST"),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "lalala",
  ),
)
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Wow @lvo I didn't knew about this widget.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TextField` with label property like this

```dart
 TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Icon',
                        
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      ),
                    )
```

[image]